When trying to export pdf or html I keep getting nbconvert is not installed but I have it installed
The output below is what I get when I'm trying to convert it. I'm using a Mac (M1) and I have jupyter, nbconvert and MacTex installed.
23:52:36.218 [info] Process Execution: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import nbconvert;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
23:52:36.468 [info] Process Execution: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import nbconvert;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
23:52:36.652 [info] Process Execution: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import pip;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
23:52:36.674 [info] Process Execution: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import nbconvert;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
23:52:36.862 [error] Export failed [Error: Jupyter nbconvert is not installedat bu.getExportInterpreter (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:321:8178)at async Cf.executeCommand (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:321:8680)at async zT.export (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:322:412)at async kb.performNbConvertExport (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:324:2500)at async kb.performExport (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:324:2190)at async kb.exportImpl (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:324:1798)at async kb.export (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:324:1530)at async C0.export (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.11.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:373:3134)at async cw.h (file:///Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:115:32825)]
23:52:36.863 [error] If you have not installed xelatex (TeX), you will need to do so before you can export to PDF. For further instructions, please see https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.To avoid installing xelatex (TeX), you might want to try exporting to HTML and using your browser's "Print to PDF" feature.

I tried uninstalling python and pip3, and uninstalling and reinstalling nbconvert.
I also added  MacTex to path with export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH, however I'm still getting this error.
I'm currently on Python 3.13.
